# Editing question when someone else edits still asks you if you want to leave the page

Tags: bug, edits

I'm reporting what may be a possible bug in Stack Overflow.  This is really minor, and probably occurs infrequently.  To reproduce this you'll need to coordinate with someone else.

What normally happens is, if you start an edit then try clicking "Back" on your browser, SO will helpfully ask you if you really meant to leave.

If your edit is interrupted, SO still thinks you're editing, even though you're not, so it still prompts if you really meant to leave.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click to edit a question.  Type in something spicy, then wait.
2. Someone else edits the question before you click to submit your spicy edit.
3. SO will notify you that someone else has edited the question.  Click to reload the question.  Your edit will disappear.
4. Try to leave the page.  SO will ask you if you really want to leave the page even though you aren't editing the question.

Comment: If you click edit again at that point, will your previous changes show up?

Comment: I actually experienced this a couple of times. Tried to edit new questions (formatting code and typos and such) that took some time and at the same time someone else also editted the question (most of the times a simple retagging).